# Trying to remove border of arc on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I drew a circle using the HTML canvas `arc` method, but I want to remove the border of the circle. I tried to set `lineWidth = 0` but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to remove the border of a circle in canvas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    pie_chart = $('#pie_chart');
    var p = pie_chart[0].getContext('2d');

    var canvas_width = pie_chart.width();
    var canvas_height = pie_chart.height();

    p.beginPath();
    p.arc(canvas_width/2, canvas_height/2, 150, 0 , Math.PI * 2);
    p.lineWidth = 0;
    p.stroke();
    p.fillStyle = '#777';
    p.fill();
});
```

Comment: Set stroke colour to be equal to fill colour?

Comment: @Amadan either that or transparent

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simple answer is: just drop the `stroke()` call:

```
p.beginPath();
p.arc(canvas_width/2, canvas_height/2, 150, 0 , Math.PI * 2);
p.lineWidth = 0;
//p.stroke();
p.fillStyle = '#777';
p.fill();
```

Comment: But then what if you want to draw a line alongside the circle? For that line, you'd have to draw it with stroke(), right? And then the border appears around the circle as well.

Comment: @ajfbiw.s you would have to use stroke for that, but also a `beginPath()` before defining the line so that the arc is not affected.

Comment: @epistemex ah correct! That's what I was missing. Thanks!